# UserControl CancelControlID working for all other controls?

Tags: c#, .net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

Hi i have created one User control which is a Popup , It is absolutely working fine , But when i click on other buttons which is other than close button it is getting closed..

Here is my code,

```
       <ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupContextInfo" runat="server" 
             TargetControlID="btnShowEditContextPopup" PopupControlID="pnlpopupContextInfo"
           CancelControlID="imgClose" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
       </ajax:ModalPopupExtender>
     < asp:Panel ID="pnlpopupContextInfo" DefaultButton="imgbtnUpdate" runat="server" BackColor="White" Height="360px" Width="400px" Style="display: none" >

       <asp:ImageButton ID="imgClose" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/image_repository/cancelButton.png" ToolTip="Close" />
      ..................
       // Code for Labels and text boxes..
         <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnCancel" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" TabIndex="8" ImageUrl="~/image_repository/cancel.png" />
         <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnUpdate" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" TabIndex="8" ImageUrl="~/image_repository/UpdateVoyage.png" />
       </asp:Panel>
```

Here when i click on Update or Cancel Button also the popup is getting closed..
how to respond the user control's button(Update here) click event from the parent web form (aspx page)

Can anyone help

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't put action. You should add `onclick="Cancel_Click1"` for example. And add the action in the server side.